# Cakephp 3.x: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 database disk image is malformed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm getting this error when I upload my application to linux. This is working fine on my local windows system but gives me error on linux server. When I search regarding this then I found this is sqLite related issue. If this is sqLite issue then how can I change this to MySQL.

Please help me.

Comment: Yes, I export my DB database from local and import to server.

Comment: try deleting the debug_kit.sqlite

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Delete the /tmp/debug_kit.sqlite

Comment: No problem sir ;) I think the debug file is getting corrupted in the debuging process. Not too sure on why is Cake throwing that error though ! +

Comment: This answer is not working for my code, can u give me another solution to solve my error?   I will appreciate u.

Comment: Are you using sqLite ?

Comment: No, I am using MySQL.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you use MySQL or SQLite for your databases - this is the db that DebugKit uses by default, hence the `.sqlite`

Comment: Also, to be safe, when moving cakephp site from one server to another make sure you don't copy over anything from tmp folder.

Comment: April 2020 and the bug is still there. How weird that deleting /tmp/debug_kit.sqlite helps. I just deleted it and it works fine..

Comment: No idea but I keep receiving stackoverflow points for it since then, I find it weird that they didnt fix that

Answer (score 6):

Delete the tmp folder

**Delete the /tmp/***

if you are getting further permission issue the set 777 permission to cakephp folder

**chmod -R 777 bookmarker**

Answer (score 4):

Delete the **/tmp/*** directory. Hope it should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the samme issue on my machine with OSX 10.11 w/ MAMP (MySQL + Apache 2)

It helped to clear the tmp/ directory within the cake3 installation - the problem persisted throughout different databases, so I figured it must have been an issue with local files rather than the database.

Answer (score 0):

#### In the Laravel SQlite Context

I got this error too. My stack is `Laravel` with `SQlite` database and `Ubuntu` as OS. In my case i tried to edit a column with the **DBBrowser for Sqlite**. But the changes domnt affected and i start to migrate again. Afterwards i got this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 database disk image is malformed
> (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" integer not null primary key
> autoincrement, "migration" varchar not null, "batch" integer not
> null))

I remove the database.sqlite with `rm pathToDatabase/database.sqlite`. After that I was able to migrate the data again.

Answer (score 0):

**Sqlite, Host machine OSX, docker container running on alpine**

I recently got the same error. During the development, I used to switch between running my application directly on my local machine (host) and a docker container. The error arises after creating my db file from OSX and then trying to read/write it from my container (Linux). Removing the database file created from OSX solved the problem.

I guess the two file systems (OSX and Linux) are different so don't mix their db files.

PS. This error is not specific to CakePHP. Mine was a #symfony app.

Answer (score -2):

This error may be caused by a hardware, file system or Operating System fault causing corruption to the Disk Safe file. Disk Safe viability, in part, relies on the stability of the underlying hardware and Operating System of the host storage device.

The safest solution is to **create a new Disk Safe** as soon as Server Backup reports that the database disk image is malformed. In some situations, the Disk Safe may still be usable for restoring recovery points that were created before the Disk Safe reported a corruption. However, we have no way to determine the extent of the corruption or if the workaround mentioned below will be able to repair the Disk Safe. In addition, we do not expect that a corrupt Disk Safe will be successful in a bare metal restore.

*You may attempt to repair the Disk Safe by running a **Disk Safe Verification (DSV)** task (introduced in Server Backup v5.2.0) against the Disk Safe with the malformed image. The DSV will check the most recent recovery point to ensure all blocks are accounted for. If the disk safe fails to verify, a repair attempt will be made during the next replication task which will attempt to reconcile any missing blocks from the recovery point.*

Comment: this answer is not correct. even if this would be a solution it is way over the top. Like building a new house, when a window broke.